# error from fetching data InvalidPathValidation

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Problem:**

app crashes with this error code.
**Edit:** calling `fetchQuests` inside initializer is the cause of this issue. If possible help me understand why calling this function will this crash my app.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation',
>   reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#'
>   '$' '[' or ']''.

I've tested this function with a few print statements and the crash occur during `query.observeSingleEvent`.

**Code:**

```
    func fetchQuests(userType: UserType) {
    quests = []

    let uid = fetchUserOrPartnerUID(userType: userType)
    // uid will return a String of user ID
    print("uid's value:", uid)

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("questsByUID").child(uid)
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "creationDate")

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

    allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] else {return}
        let quest = Quest(uid: uid, dictionary: dictionary)
        quest.questID = snapshot.key

        self.quests.append(quest)
    })

    self.delegate?.questsUpdated(quests: self.quests)

    }) { (err) in
    print("unable to fetch quest:", err)
     }
    }
```

**print state from uid:**

uid's value: NbYbOIjwYNQ8flqqIUOTUrG1Obn2

**Edited:**

I found what went wrong with my code. It's actually not my `fetchQuests` itself that cause this crash. it's actually calling `fetchQuests` inside initializer that led to this issue. Can someone explain to me why I can't do that as an answer?

```
init(userType: UserType, acceptedQuests: Bool, completedQuests: Bool) {
//        self.fetchQuests(userType: userType)
    self.questsAcceptedFilter = !acceptedQuests
    self.questCompletedFilter = !completedQuests
    print("fetching quests")
}
```

Comment: What value does `fetchUserOrPartnerUID(userType: userType)` return?

Comment: it will return a String represent user's ID.

Comment: please add this statement `print(uid)` after `let uid = fetchUserOrPartnerUID(userType: userType)` and check what does it print

Comment: issue is with uid you are passing in handler, Print UID and see what string value you actually receive if no special character are received , get the uid first trimmed out of all white spaces and then use it , Hope it helps

Comment: uid's value: NbYbOIjwYNQ8flqqIUOTUrG1Obn2